# Clash between tinyMCE popup and DataTables with server side processing

Tags: tinymce, server-side, datatables

I need to have table (with thousands of rows) inside tinyMCE popup, so that user can filter / select a row and insert it into editor window. So I have DataTables, with server side processing and filtering. Relevant code is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../tiny_mce_popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready( function() {
    var respTable = $('#resp_table').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'insert_resp.php',
        ...
```

..etc.

The JSON response is good,

```
"sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":"18783","iTotalDisplayRecords":"18783","aaData":[["0","1","2","3","4","5"],["0","1","2","3","4","5"]]
```

It works perfectly, **but only if** I exclude the tinymce popup script that allows to get the result back into editor window:

```
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../../tiny_mce_popup.js"></script>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready( function() {
    var respTable = $('#resp_table').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'insert_resp.php',
        ...
```

This way of course the 'tinyMCEPopup is not defined' error pops out, but table works.

Without commenting it out, there is no errors in console, no warnings, the XHR request and response is the same, but Datatables shows 'processing' and table is not populated with data.

And if I include the response directly into table init, it works, too:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../tiny_mce_popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dialog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready( function() {
    var respTable = $('#resp_table').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'insert_resp.php',
        "sEcho":"1","iTotalRecords":"18783","iTotalDisplayRecords":"18783","aaData":[["0","1","2","3","4","5"],["0","1","2","3","4","5"]],
        ...
```

With this last bit of script, one could think that my JSON response is faulty, but it works fine when I comment out the first (tinymce popup) line..

Also, in tinyMCE plugins folder, in /js/dialog.js, the 1st line is

```
tinyMCEPopup.requireLangPack();
```

If I comment that out, the DataTables work.. Inside en_dlg.js that it refers to, is

```
tinyMCE.addI18n('en.linktest_dlg',{
  //title : 'Title',
  //insert : 'Insert it',
  //cancel : 'Back'
});
```

Commented out or not, this seems to be the culprit. Isn't that weird..

Could anyone teach me what is happening here? I've spent three days scratching my head, it hurts..